# How can I feed extract or date_part with a dynamic query-derived value in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to modify a query to **extract** day, week, month, etc from a date where the field in "extract(field from datetime)" is provided by query values.

This is for Redshift. The simplified example I'm working on is below. Trying to create a summary for various date buckets without repeating the same query over and over.

```
SELECT
    visit_start_date,
    period_type,
    extract(period_type from visit_start_date) as Period
FROM f_visit_dates
  cross join d_period_type
```

Input table named f_visit_dates
with single date column visit_start_date and two rows:

```
visit_start_date
---------------- 
 '2017-03-14'
 '2018-05-06'
```

Input table named d_period_type contains five rows and one varchar(10) column:

```
period_type
-----------
'day'
'week'
'month'
'quarter'
'year'
```

Output should look like the following:

```
visit_start   period_type   period
-----------   -----------   ------
2017-03-14    day             73
2017-03-14    week            11
2017-03-14    month            3
2017-03-14    quarter          1
2017-03-14    year          2017
2018-05-06    day            126
2018-05-06    week            18
2018-05-06    month            5
2018-05-06    quarter          2
2018-05-06    year          2018
```

I should add that the above as written doesn't work, obviously. I've also tried supplying the value through a "WITH" clause but that also doesn't work.

Comment: cat you try using date_trunc instead as that takes a literal string value

Comment: Please edit your question and supply a sample set of input data and an example of what you want the output to be. Please keep it as simple as possible to focus on the specific issue you are facing (eg remove the bits that aren't relevant to the question, such as `COUNT (distinct...)`).

Comment: I've edited the question as requested. Also, date_trunc does not work.